# bootstrap navbar dropdown not working after ajax call

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-4

I have a page that a user can comment on and the navbar dropdowns(both submenus and the menu itself when it automatically adjusts to a smaller screen) stop working properly. What's odd is that it stops working after the user adds every odd comment(1st, 3rd, 5th, etc.).

ajax:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/addComment',
        data: {postId: postId, text: text},
        success: function(data) {
            $('#comments-container').append(data);

        }
    })
```

navbar:

```
<nav id="navbar" class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="home"><img src="/imgs/it.png" width="50px"> catvas</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item {{#if home_active}}active{{/if}}">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/home">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item {{#if explore_active}}active{{/if}} dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                  <i class="fas fa-camera"></i> Explore
                </a>
                <ul role="menu" id="explore" name="explore" class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                  <a class="dropdown-item {{#if adopt_active}}active-drop{{/if}}" href="/adoptCat"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i> Adopt a Cat</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item {{#if catfeed_active}}active-drop{{/if}}" href="/catFeed"><i class="fas fa-comments"></i> View Catfeed</a>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item {{#if team_active}}active{{/if}}">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/team"><i class="fas fa-code"></i> Meet the Team</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item {{#if faq_active}}active{{/if}}">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/faq"><i class="fas fa-question"></i> FAQ</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item {{#if donate_active}}active{{/if}}">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/donate"> <i class="fas fa-box-open"></i> Donate to Catvas</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item {{#if login_active}}active{{/if}}">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/login"><i class="fas fa-cat"></i> Login </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item {{#if signup_active}}active{{/if}}">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/signup"><i class="fas fa-paw"></i> Sign Up</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

layout:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/script.js"></script> 

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <div id="navContainer">
        {{> nav}}
    </div>
```